# Safari wrapping TD without expanding table

Tags: html, css, safari, html-table, word-wrap

Question:
How do you prevent Safari 7 from wrapping the content inside of the TD's in the fiddler example?

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/fRxdG/6/

Code:

```
<style>

    .slide {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        margin: 5px;
        float:left;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
</style>
<div style="overflow:auto">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> 
                <span class="slide">something</span>
                <span class="slide">something</span> 
            </td>
            <td> 
                <span class="slide">something</span>
                <span class="slide">something</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="slide">something</span>
                <span class="slide">something</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Setup:

The example contains a div that is set to overflow:auto. Inside the containing div there is a table with a single row and three table cells. In each of the table cells there are two divs that contain text.

In Safari 7 the table is not automatically expanding to fit it's content. If the table is set to a specific width, say width:10000px, the table puts the content on one line instead of wrapping it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<table width="auto">
```

Comment: `<table width="auto">`

Does not change the behavior of the wrapping.